# WordPress: Which hook working when the post deleted permanently from wp admin

Tags: php, wordpress, post, notifications, hook

I'm trying to create a function that fires whenever a post is deleted permanently not trashed, and I deleting all the posts from wp admin directly and permanently!

it's working but sometimes sends one notification, sometimes two and sometimes sends all of them at the same time!

also sometimes fires when I updating the post!!

How can i be sure to send only one notification for each post status, and working only when I deleted the post permanently?

```
function deleted_post_notify_author( $post ) {

    global $post;

        $post = get_post($post->ID);
        $author = $post->post_author;
        $author_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author );
        $link =  '#';
        $image = '/images/sad-icon-01.svg';

    if( current_user_can('administrator')) {

         if( $post->post_status == 'pending' ) {

        $title = '<strong>'.$author_name.'</strong> ' . __('We are sorry to inform you that your artwork has been declined', 'dw-notifications'). ' <strong>'.$post->post_title.'</strong>';

        } elseif ( $post->post_status == 'publish' ) {

        $title = '<strong>'.$author_name.'</strong> ' . __('We are sorry to inform you that your artwork has been deleted because did not reached after 4 days 100 views at least', 'dw-notifications'). ' <strong>'.$post->post_title.'</strong>';

        } else {

        $title = '<strong>'.$author_name.'</strong> ' . __('We are sorry to inform you that all draft posts will be delete. if you want to publish your project click submit for review', 'dw-notifications'). ' <strong>'.$post->post_title.'</strong>';

        }
        $notif = array('title'=>$title, 'link' => $link, 'image' => $image);
        dwnotif_add_notification($author, $notif);
    }
}
add_action( 'after_delete_post', 'deleted_post_notify_author' );
```

Comment: so it is sending multiple notifications for one post deletion?

Comment: Yes sometimes! also sending when I updated the post.

Comment: Hello @CoderJoe, I don't mean to bother you, but there are any hope to fix this issue, Thank you!

Comment: The permanent solution would be to debug the scenario and see where it is sending multiple times at by stepping through the code at key points, also checking to see if you have this code in multiple places or on other hooks, for a temporary fix however you can store the notification in the database and before sending cross reference the database to see if it has already been sent

However I do not recommend the latter because it is a patch not a fix